# Creating two Foreign keys in one table

Tags: mysql

I have tried to create two foreign keys within the one table but I get the following error message : #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Here is my sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (

  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `users_id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `users_name` varchar(50),

  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

 FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users (id),

 FOREIGN KEY (users_name) REFERENCES users (name)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Did you define the `users` table before running the above `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Yes, I already have a users table this worked for me when I had just one foreign key but as soon as I added another one it failed.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but why you _need_ a second foreign key?  The user's `id` should already uniquely determine what the name is.

Comment: Is the name attribute a primary key? in another table

Comment: Thanks Tim, I forgot I can use {{ Auth::user()->name } thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the column you are pointing is  primary key

```
 FOREIGN KEY (users_name) REFERENCES users (name)
```

Check whether name is a primary key.

Comment: If you specify the foreign column, it doesn't have to be a primary key. If you omit it, ie just `REFERENCES user`, the foreign column is assumed to be the primary key.

Comment: Thanks, the name column isn't a primary key? would I have to make it a primary key in the users table in order for this to work?

Comment: I'm not going to use the two foreign keys now it works fine with one and I forgot in laravel I can use {{ Auth::user()->name } thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

@NiamhFlannery firstly  y dont u use laravel migrations.

you dont need user_name in this table u can fetch it by joining the tables.

you can use relationships in models

In user model you can specify hasMany() and in files models you can specify belongsTo().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot in laravel I can use {{ Auth::user()->name } thanks for your help

Comment: thats one way but to fetch user name you dont need to store it redundantly in database, you can use join and then fetch and show the details.

Comment: So, I have a table with uploads from various users I want to display the users name beside the upload that belongs to them? How would I use join and fetch?

Comment: This is complex but let me try to frame it for you

Answer (score 0):

User Model

```
public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('FilesModels', 'user_id', 'id);
    }
```

Files Model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
```

While fetching records

```
$files = Files::with('user')->select(*)->get();
```

if you return the above query data u will find user object with each record.

You can access the same with

```
@foreach($files as $key => $file)
{
    echo "user id = " . $file->user->id .' \n';
    echo "user name = " . $file->user->user_name .' \n';
}
```

Comment: I will try and implement this thanks for your help. I would ideally like to get the foreign key added to the files table as this seems easier for me. I'm pretty new to all this so the above may take me a while to figure out